# Make canvas responsive

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have tried debugging my JavaScript for its correctness. I t seems the values for innerwidth and innerheight is passing correctly. But i am not able to get responsive canvas.

Javascript:

```
var chartW = 0.848, sliderW = 0.888;
var chartTop, chartLeft, chartWidth, chartHeight, nTools;
function draw_TeeChart() {

    var w = window.innerWidth, h = window.innerHeight;

    // Initialize Teechart
    Chart1 = new Tee.Chart("canvas");

    document.getElementById("canvas").style.position  = "relative";
    document.getElementById("canvas").width= Math.round(0.855*w);document.getElementById("canvas").height= Math.round(0.89*h);  //Chart1.bounds.x = Math.round(0.01*w);

    Chart1.bounds.x = 14;Chart1.bounds.y= 10;
    Chart1.bounds.width = Math.round(chartW*w);Chart1.bounds.height= Math.round(0.88*h);
    Chart1.legend.visible = false; Chart1.panel.transparent = true;
    Chart1.title.visible = false;Chart1.axes.bottom.title.text = " ";
    Chart1.axes.left.increment = 1; Chart1.axes.bottom.increment = 0.50;
    Chart1.walls.back.format.fill = wallColorCode;
    Chart1.walls.back.format.shadow.visible = false;
    document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
```

html:

```
<canvas id="canvas" class="contextCanvas"></canvas>

css:

.contextCanvas {
    position: relative;
    top:-3%;
}
```

Could someone please suggest me how to make my canvas responsive where it can fit different devices?

Comment: can you try adding 'px' to height and width of canvas

Comment: I just realized after debugging through several lines it does resize to different screen sizes but only after performing few actions related to canvas.. such play forward to play different channels on the on the canvas. it is not resizing by itself. should i have to write a code where it says onNewwindow(){resize;}

Comment: Hi can anyone please suggest me a piece of code which might work for me?